# Add CGPDFDocumentRef to NSDictionary or NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the appropriate way to treat a `CGPDFDocumentRef` object so that it can be added to `NSArray` and then easily retrieved back in its `CGPDFDocumentRef` form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add CGPDFDocumentRef to your NSArray or NSMutableArray as long as you cast them to appropriate types when adding/accessing.

Here is a sample code that I tested:

```
CFStringRef path;
CFURLRef url;
CGPDFDocumentRef document;

NSString *nsstringPath = [[NSURL pathForDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];

path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, [nsstringPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);

CFRelease (path);
document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL (url);
CFRelease(url);
count = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages (document);

NSMutableArray *testArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[test addObject:(__bridge id)(document)];

CGPDFDocumentRef testPdf = (__bridge CGPDFDocumentRef)([testArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) to Apple docs covering toll-free bridging. It covers Foundation framework though, but should give an idea.

Hope this helps, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It was posted earlier today using different object, but I can't find it currently.

You can create an NSValue object to add to the array.  Not sure how it works, just regurgitating information here:

```
[NSValue valueForBytes:(pointer) objCType:@encode(CGPDFDocumentRef)];
```

Comment: You could also do `[NSValue valueWithPointer:CGPDFDocumentRef]` and then `ref=(CGPDFDocumentRef)[nsvalue pointerValue];`